# Complex analysis residue problem. $\oint_\gamma \frac{\sin^2(z)}{(z-1)^2} \,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am studying for my math exam.

Here is a problem that has stumped me for quite a while now...

$\displaystyle \oint_\gamma \frac{\sin^2(z)}{(z-1)^2} \,dz$

Where $\gamma$ is the circle of radius one centered at $z=1$. I know this problem is asking me to find the residue, but the only techiniques I know for doing this is by expanding $\displaystyle \sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+...$ and maybe by expanding $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}=(1+z+z^2+...)^2$

Comment: If you want to do it via expanding series, then you should be expanding the sine about $1$, not $0$.

Comment: You can either use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles) or, if you want to solve via series expansion, you can use [example 1 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Series_methods), which is in line with what Ninad explained above.

Comment: Thank you very much. Which one do you think will be faster to compute with on average?

Comment: The fastest approach is usually problem dependent, so I don't think there is a 'faster way' in general. For example, if you have a pole of large enough order, then computing derivatives will become tedious, so it might be faster to use a series expansion, where as if the pole order is small, then getting the full series expansion might be overkill. I would just learn to do both as well as possible, complex integration is a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z):= \sin^2(z)$. Then $\displaystyle \oint_\gamma \frac{\sin^2(z)}{(z-1)^2} \,dz=\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-1)^2} \,dz = 2 \pi f'(1)$, by Cauchy's integral formula.